# How to present a table view on an iPad to best utilize available screen real estate?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, user-interface

I'm developing an application for the iPad.  On the first screen the user is required to select from a list of options (about 10 - 15). I'm using a table view for the purpose. However on the large iPad screen I feel like I'm not quite using the screen real estate the best way possible. This is because each cell in my table view just consists of a title (no detail description & thumbnail image).

I was wondering as to how I can create an attractive user interface to present the limited list of options. I've seen that what apple does in most of its iPas applications is have multiple table views side by side (2 in case of portrait & 3 in case of landscape).

However in my application there simply aren't that many options in order to need multiple table views. Any ideas?

Comment: There is an old 'Cocoa with love' [sample](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) for that. You can also find there the link to the sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a split view, I think it's more attractive...